# Some Excel cells stay unpopulated, with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm writing an application that opens an existing `.xlsx` file and writes to certain cells.

Some cells write correctly, where others just stay blank?

Any ideas?

This is a snippet of code

The same code for the cells that are and arent working, except that the index's changed

```
oSheet.Cells[3, 15] = "1"; // this doesnt write to the cell 
oSheet.Cells[7, 7] = "1"; // this writes to the cell
```

All that i could think is that there is a formatting issue in the Excel file?

Comment: Could you post your code that is not working?

Comment: Quick suggestion: Edit your question to include the code rather than using comments.

Comment: Check that the cells are not locked and the columns/rows are not hidden. Also check that you're looking in cell [3, 15] and not [15, 3]. Just as a possibility.

Comment: Check that [3,15] is not part of a merged range.  A merged range will ONLY get the value if you specify the upper left cell of the merged range.  If you specify any other cell, it will not write the value into the cell nor pop an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anthony was right, I had my columns and rows switched.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working in Excel for years and find quirks like this all the time.  If you are in .NET 4.0 try this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel    

//Other Class code
var range = oSheet.Cells[3, 15];
range.Value2 = "1";
```

Otherwise, try this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel    

//Other Class code

Excel.Range range = (Excel.Rang)oSheet.Cells[3, 15];
range.Value2 = "1";
```

Value2 seems to work more consistently, so I generally recommend using it.

Cheers!